# The description of politics, geography etc of Forgotten Realms

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, lore

I remember there was a separate book for D&D 3.5 describing all about Forgotten Realms. My question is - is there a book which describes it for 5e?

Comment: The topics you listed, "politics, geography etc", should be edition-independent. Are you looking for a book that contains or refers to game mechanics or is there another reason to ask specifically about a 5e book?

Comment: Are you looking for a 5e version of [this](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Forgotten_Realms_Campaign_Guide)?

Comment: I'm looking for 5e specific because as far as I know the settings's changed for 5e.

Comment: @Nwp: They are not "edition independent". Each edition advanced the timeline. 4E brought with it the Spellplague, as a way to explain the game's mechanical changes. 5E brought the Second Sundering, as a way to explain the return to older style mechanics. These events included changes to the landscape and the toppling of governments.

Answer (score 8):

The only official book I can think of that describes Forgotten Realms lore in detail for 5e is the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*.

The first couple of chapters are all about the Realms, it's history and geography, etc, before following up with how the classes and races from the PHB fit into the Realms specifically.

It also includes a few Realms-specific class archetypes such as Bladesingers and Long Death monks, as well as being the only place (that I'm aware of) where the stats for Duergar as a playable race exist.

Comment: Duergar as playable race will also be listed in the upcoming Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, if [this preview](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/mordenkainen%E2%80%99s-tome-foes-preview) is anything to go by.

Comment: Most of the Lore in SCAG handles the western coast, a great deal of what is further inland is left uncovered, such as Cormyr and Thay.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the *Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide*, each of the flagship hardbound adventures describes some part of the Forgotten Realms in detail. For example, *Tomb of Annihilation* describes Chult.